# HTML attributes missing in sending email

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Sending mail inside wordpress admin. Headers:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

With From/Reply-to headers its didnt work;

In the `<a>` tag inside the letter all attrs( `href`, `style` ) is gone. 
Message i get from `$_REQUEST`, `textarea` tag where href display correct. 
IF i use a constant string as argument for mail, links work properly. Please help.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @MHakvoort, i send <a href="http://somesite.com">Some text</a> and recieve <a>Some text</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by myself.
textarea send text with escape symbols ( \" instead " ). After removing its work

Answer (score 0):

Please compare second line .

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: download from git and implement it will be better 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: He asked for solution, how you think to force him to use phpmailer?

Comment: I am not forcing...just suggestion...dear

Comment: compare  your code from w3school http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp example 3

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your second line with:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

This is taken from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: didnt help, and that charset is not for my message